# What drives intercalation?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_(chemistry)):

> intercalation is the reversible inclusion or insertion of a molecule
>   (or ion) into compounds with layered structures.

What is the "driving force" / mechanism that's responsible for intercalation? I assume it's not just diffusion.

In particular, why intercalation continues beyond the periphery? i.e. imagine the process has started and the periphery is now occupied by the intercalant: what drives subsequent intercalation to occur if all the periphery is already occupied by low energy host-guest arrangements?

Comment: There is no such 'driving force'. Diffusion will cause the two species to collide but while adjacent there has to be an enthalpic (intermolecular interaction energy) or entropic reason for their mutual interaction to cause intercalation so prevent the species  from diffusing apart. Whether energy or entropy or some of both causes the free energy to become favourable vs. separated species may depend on the individual species involved.

Comment: @porphyrin if that is the case, wouldn't you expect intercalation to occur only at the periphery?

Comment: I would expect that possibly millions of collisions between the host & guest  occur before one that leads to intercalation, clearly the approach direction has to be approx correct but once there is some interaction (even at some odd geometry) as long as it is greater than kT on average  ($\approx 210 \pu{cm^{-1}}$) then intercalating will begin to win out.

Comment: @porphyrin sure, but now imagine the periphery is occupied by the intercalant. What drives subsequent intercalation to occur if all the periphery is already occupied by low energy host-guest arrangements?

Comment: Things are not static, if this is the case at some point one peripheral guest will leave (due to thermal fluctuations) and so may become fully intercalated or move away altogether. Its just a random thing, but given enough tries,  and there will be millions of them, intercalation will happen if it is the lowest energy state and this is several times kT lower than peripheral energy binding. The intercalated guest may also leave the host, its largely about the energy vs thermal energy although entropy may play a part depending on solvent.